# Modifying blueimp jquery uploader

Tags: php, jquery, blueimp, uploader

I'm modifying this code in order to use in my php web. I added the code to my *index.php* , but I don't know where to add the  `Client-side file upload initialization:`  part of the code ?

Here is the codes which I used inorder to make uploader inserts into mysql db.

Client-side file upload initialization:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/php/'
}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in file **main.js** for old code below add comment

```
/* 
    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'server/php/'
    });
*/
```

add new code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/php/'
    }).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
     data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
});
```